# How to end animation of gif image in android

Tags: android, animated-gif

Hello all first I apologize for this silly question however I couldn't fix this.
I have an splash screen where I have used an gif image thats animates.I just want the animation of gif image once and stop.However, I am not getting that.My gif image animation continues to animate till the slash screen appears.For example I have set splash time to 4 sec.What I wish to do is to animate gif image for just 2 seconds and stop at it is or stop as the animation ends.

This is my Gif Class:

```
public class GIFView extends View {
    public Movie mMovie;
    public long movieStart;

    public GIFView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initializeView();
    }

    public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initializeView();
    }

    public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initializeView();
    }

    private void initializeView() {
        InputStream is = getContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.splash_tick);
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (movieStart == 0) {
            movieStart = now;
        }
        if (mMovie != null) {
            int relTime = (int) ((now - movieStart) % mMovie.duration());
            mMovie.setTime(relTime);
            mMovie.draw(canvas, getWidth() - mMovie.width(), getHeight() - mMovie.height());
            this.invalidate();
        }
    }
    private int gifId;

    public void setGIFResource(int resId) {
        this.gifId = resId;
        initializeView();
    }

    public int getGIFResource() {
        return this.gifId;
    }
}
```

Please help me to achieve this.Thanks in advance